# Characterizing $T \in L(V)$ if $\dim V = 2$ and $T^2 = {\rm Id}_V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Assume $V$ is a $\mathbb{K}-$vector space with $\dim V = 2$, and let $T \in L(V)$ such that $T^2 = {\rm Id}_V$. I must prove that either $T = \pm {\rm Id}_V$ or $$[T]_{\cal B} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0& - 1\end{bmatrix}$$in some basis ${\cal B}$.

If $T \neq \pm {\rm Id}_V$, we take $v,u \in V$ with $v \neq -Tv$ and $u \neq Tu$. So if $\tilde{v} = v+Tv$ and $\tilde{u} = u - Tu$, then ${\cal B} = (\tilde{v},\tilde{u})$ fits the bill.

I'm having trouble checking that this is linearly independent to finish the exercise. If $a,b \in \Bbb K$ are such that $a\tilde{v}+b\tilde{u} = 0$, applying $T$ gives $a\tilde{v}-b\tilde{u} = 0$, and so $2a=2b = 0$. If ${\rm char}(\Bbb K) \neq 2$, done. If ${\rm char}(\Bbb K) = 2$ I'm not sure what to do. Help?

Comment: What you are trying to prove is not true in characteristic $2$.  Try $T=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ in some basis.

Comment: If $\mathrm{char}(\mathbb{K})=2$ then $-1=1$ and the matrix you have exhibited is the identity matrix. Is this helpful or am I just revealing my ignorance?

Comment: @Bat false the result, or false that $\{\tilde{v},\tilde{u}\}$ is linearly independent?

Comment: @Will that is actually helpful, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\operatorname{char} \mathbb{K} = 2$ then the statement doesn’t hold.
Consider for example the $\mathbb{F}_2$-linear map $T \colon \mathbb{F}_2^2 \to \mathbb{F}_2^2$ which is given by multiplication with the matrix
$$
  A
  :=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 \\
    0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}
  \in
  M_2(\mathbb{F}).
$$
Then $T^2$ is given by multiplication with the matrix
$$
  A^2
  =
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 \\
    0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}
  =
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix},
$$
which is just the identity matrix.
Therefore $T^2 = \operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{F}^2_2}$.

Because $A$ is not the identity matrix we know that $T \neq \operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{F}^2_2}$.
By using that $1 = -1$ in $\mathbb{F}_2$ we find that $T$ does not satisfy any of the three given conditions, all of which are in this case equivalent to $T$ being the identity.

Comment: Seems good. Thanks!